# How to get index value in python (multi index)

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I am creating a tool which compares two dataframes and returns details about differences in excel file.

Example of report with differences where TC stands for Test case which contains differences, fields column represents name of fields which contains differences:

```
TC  Fields  Baseline    New output
1   B         34           28
    C          4           25

3   C          5           28

5   B          7           23
    C          8           2
    D          6           24
```

Baseline file (baseline df):

```
TC   A        B       C       D
1   22,00   27,00   24,00   25,00
2   23,00   34,00   4,00    27,00
3   24,00   2,00    27,00   28,00
5   25,00   2,00    5,00    2,00
6   27,00   22,00   2,00    2,00
7   28,00   7,00    8,00    6,00
9   2,00    24,00   24,00   25,00
10  2,00    25,00   25,00   2,00
```

New Output file (new df):

```
TC    A       B      C        D
1   22,00   27,00   24,00   25,00
2   23,00   28,00   25,00   27,00
3   24,00   2,00    27,00   28,00
5   25,00   2,00    28,00   2,00
6   27,00   22,00   2,00    2,00
7   28,00   23,00   2,00    24,00
9   2,00    24,00   24,00   25,00
10  2,00    25,00   25,00   2,00
```

As you can see for example in Fields column of report file there are 3 fields with differences for, as it says, TC 5, but if you check baseline and new output file you will see that these differences are acctually related to TC 7 from the files.

Here is the code exmple:

```
def writeDetailsAboutDifferencesToNewExcelSheet(dfBaseline, dfNew):
    assert (dfBaseline.columns == dfNew.columns).all(), \
        "DataFrame column names are different"
    if dfBaseline.equals(dfNew):
        return None
    else:
        diff_mask = (dfBaseline != dfNew) & ~(dfBaseline.isnull() & dfNew.isnull())
        ne_stacked = diff_mask.stack()
        changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]
        changed.index.names = ['TC', 'Fields']
        difference_locations = np.where(diff_mask)
        changed_from = dfBaseline.values[difference_locations]
        changed_to = dfNew.values[difference_locations]
        df =  pd.DataFrame( {'Baseline': changed_from, 'New output': changed_to} , index=changed.index)
        return df
```

The problem is that it returns index number in report instead of the value of the corresponding index from the data frame or better to say I don't know how to return value of the index of the TC which contains differences so that fields with differences fits the number of TC and not the number of its index?

Can you please let me know if you have some idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think your values TC1 are wrong too.

Comment: Yes, but I took TC5 as an example, it is same for all. If you take a look at TC 1 from report you will see that it coresponds actually to TC2 and that is what I would like to correct :) I believe that it happens because in TC column I return index value instead of the value of the wrong TC and the index starts from 0 and increments for 1 while value of the TC column can be any int.